# HTML not Loading CSS , after refresh everything works. Also on mobile's it doesnt work on first load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've customized some template and for some reason CSS is not loaded on first entry on some browsers. What is worst it does not load for first time on phones too. I thought that cloudflare is to blame, I ve disabled it and problem still remain.

URL is: http://www.vodoinstalaterbeograd.net

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: What browsers in particular? I'm seeing it load in Chrome, though I get a Flash of Unstyled Content first.

Comment: It mostly happens on android's default browser, and sometime on FireFox.

Comment: I'm using chrome and it doesn't load any CSS

Comment: Exactly, sometimes it load and sometimes it does not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put your main css style inside `<noscript></noscript>` tag. At least try bringing your main css style out of the tag and put extra style inside it:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<noscript>
<link href="css/skel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/style-xlarge.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</noscript>
```

or even completely remove `<noscript></noscript>` because I think you don't need it there.

Comment: i ve deleted noscript tags, it renders background but whole css is not loaded as it is supposed to be.

Comment: I checked your website in chrome. Your css is loading after a while. I mean first there's no style, but after a minute or two it begins to show up. it shows that your css styles is loading after the page scripts finish being loaded.

Comment: thank you, it works now :) Tho the tags came with theme. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the top of he page I see:

```
<script data-rocketsrc="js/jquery.min.js" async type="text/rocketscript"></script>
<script data-rocketsrc="js/jquery.scrolly.min.js" async type="text/rocketscript"></script>
<script data-rocketsrc="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js" async type="text/rocketscript"></script>
<script data-rocketsrc="js/jquery.scrollex.min.js" async type="text/rocketscript"></script>
<script data-rocketsrc="js/skel.min.js" async type="text/rocketscript"></script>
<script data-rocketsrc="js/skel-layers.min.js" async type="text/rocketscript"></script>
<script data-rocketsrc="js/init.js" async type="text/rocketscript"></script>
```

At the bottom:

```
<script type="text/rocketscript">
  var _paq = _paq || [];
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function() {
    var u="//www.stats.vaskir.com/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', 3]);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();
</script>
```

I would guess is that the page is loading (with no styles), The end of the page page  script fires, and Javascript is causing the scripts to load & execute, formatting your page.
try editing teh script tage in the way the code is doing, to prove that is the case, then understand whay it is doing what it needs to.

May be as simple as putting the code atthe bottom of the page at the top, after the script tag.